# iPhone 5s IOS update problems

Tags: ios, software-update

My storage is almost full, I can't seem to update my IOS. Is there a way to update my iPhone 5s when my storage is almost full?

Comment: Sometimes restarting can change the apparent free space. Also, updating from iTunes can take less space than over the air; you can also delete the existing update file from your phone first. Otherwise, it's as @Buscar웃SD says.

Answer (score 1):

Every update also shows how much space is needed. It will also check that for you when you try to update and let you know.

If you have some free space, but not enough to update over the air, you can either [update using iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204#itunes) or [delete content manually](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6502?viewlocale=en_US) from your device. Whether you use iTunes or update over the air, you'll have the same amount of free space on your device after you update.

Before you start make sure you know your AppleID and password.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what Buscar웃SD said, quoted below, it may be more possible using iTunes simply because when you do an OTA (over the air) update, you have to first download the large installer to your phone which then has to unpack itself into the phones memory and still have space to process all the instructions and install itself into the phone. Space has to be available for that to happen in that case where as if it is downloaded to your computer, you stand a better chance.

> Every update also shows how much space is needed. It will also check that for you when you try to update and let you know.
>
> If you have some free space, but not enough to update over the air,
>   you can either update using iTunes or delete content manually from
>   your device. Whether you use iTunes or update over the air, you'll
>   have the same amount of free space on your device after you update.
>
> Before you start make sure you know your AppleID and password.